# Click and focus power bi behaviour

Tags: powerbi

I would like to know if it's possible to change the power bi automatic feature when you click on a portion of a donut or pie diagram, and it automatically shows proportionally those portion on the others diagram by showing two shade, one darker and one clearer, of the same color. What I would like to change is the shape of the darker highlighted color, in the donut diagram like shown in the first pictures i would like to have a portion of the donut, but not radial like now, but a slice. Same in the pie chart, i would like to have a portion of the pie, not a shorter pie like it is now. Thanks in advance for the help

[image: power bi diagram focus]

[image: power bi diagram focus]

Answer (score 1):

Great idea! You can present it here
https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/
and it will surely be implemented sooner or later.

Comment: thanks, so I take it as a no, there is no such option :)